# Minimizing AWS EC2 instances for a basic CI -> Staging -> Prod setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-deployment

I'm looking into getting an AWS environment set-up for a new project. This would begin as a single app (with a PostgreSQL database) with a deployment pipeline that is relatively robust (for releasing betas etc), but not overkill. I have read plenty of guides but not found any that cover my particular setup.

I think the bare minimum would be a CI environment, and staging/prod environments - all on EC2. My question is - what is the best way to mimimise the number of instances (and thus the instance hours used - you get 750 in the free trial)?

Could you dockerise one instance and have a Jenkins container and staging environment? Would it be mad to also put the prod environment in a container to only use one instance?

If you have any guides in addition to advice that would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While the free-tier provides ample resources for learning and experimenting with AWS, it is unlikely to provide enough resources to support a robust deployment pipeline. The free-tier provides 720 hours a month of t2.micro instances. You could separate your CI environment across a couple t2.micro instances and only have them running when necessary (as to not exceed 720 total hours), but I am still skeptical your pipeline will have sufficient resources. If the t2.micro instances will run your Docker containers then, sure, by all means go for it.

A good first step would be to figure out exactly what resources (instance types, storage, etc.) are required and then go from there.

Comment: OK cool. I guess CI resources are fine to establish need by trial and error, but I should probably investigate what would be the best selections for my production environment. Are there any rough rules of thumb around application demand vs AWS instance (e.g. Number of hits expected per hour corresponding to a particular instance)?